# Teenagers make up the majority of the population

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

According to a dictionary 'make up something' means to combine together to form something larger. Have I used 'make up' correctly in the following sentences?

1. *In Yemen people who are 60 plus **make up the smallest percentage of the population** in both years.*
2. *Even though in Yemen kids and teenagers **make up the majority of the population** in 2000, at 50.1%, in 2050 the percentage will go down to 37%.*

Comment: Common synonyms of *make up* in this sense are *constitute*, *compose* and *represent*. Many people also use *comprise*, as in *teenagers comprise the majority of the population*, even though this usage is called incorrect by some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is quite an idiomatic.

A good way to tell if a phrase is being used correctly is to look for examples of it used online.  You do need to be careful, since you can find lots of bad English online. So look for examples in books, newspapers and major website.  Major articles on English Wikipedia get edited by native speakers so usually, the English is usually quite typical of the English of native speakers.  I quickly found the article on the demographics of the USA by searching for "make up" "of the population", which contains the sentence:

> "Non-Hispanic Whites" make up 60.7% of the country's population.

Here, "make up" is being used in the same way as you have used it.  This is a common and natural use.

Answer (score 1):

You have used "make up" correctly in the context of those sentences.

It is commonly used when describing parts of a set in terms of percentage or fraction.

> Dogs made up half of the pets at the park yesterday.

> Males make up more than 75% of transit operators in the city.

I would argue that definition you wrote is slightly different than how I would define it or have seen it defined, though.

Saying "to combine together" sounds as if you are actively doing the combining, while the common usage in this sense is more passive. It's usually done in noting, describing or recording an amount of one group or one type of thing relative to a larger group.

[Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/make-up) puts it simply:

> to form something

You could also say something like:

> England, Wales, Scotland and Northern Ireland make up the United Kingdom.

By the way, I'd say the most common uses of "make up" in a verbal form are:

1. To create something from imagination, such as a story, plan, lie, etc.
2. To reconcile with someone after a fight or a disagreement

Another one is to "put on cosmetics," but then "make" and "up" are usually separated by the subject of the action.

> I want to make my face up to look like a geisha.